# KStream repeatable in case of error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I have the following implementation

```
    @Bean
    public KStream<Integer, String> kStream(StreamsBuilder kStreamBuilder) {
        KStream<Integer, String> stream = kStreamBuilder.stream("streamingTopic1");
        stream
                .mapValues(String::toUpperCase)
                .groupByKey()
                .reduce((String value1, String value2) -> value1 + value2,
                        TimeWindows.of(1000),
                        "windowStore")
                .toStream()
                .map((windowedId, value) -> new KeyValue<>(windowedId.key(), value))
                .filter((i, s) -> s.length() > 40)
                .to("streamingTopic2");

        stream.print();

        return stream;
    }
```

and I would like in case of any error to keep retrying until the message has been send. I am aware of the Retryable annotation but I don't see anyway on how to handle the exception thrown and try again.

Comment: `retrying until the message has been send.` -> Where's that part in your code?

Comment: Well, I don't know how to put that part together. I know the retryable annotation must be on another method in a different class and should be managed by Spring but is there a way to create a bean that will catch the exception?

Comment: Where's the `send message` code? Is that `stream.print`?

Comment: Nope, is the `.to("streamingTopic2");` that does the sending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See `StreamsConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG`

> "Setting a value greater than zero will cause the client to resend any request that fails with a potentially transient error.";

The kafka client itself will retry

also

> public static final String RETRY_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG = "retry.backoff.ms";
>
> public static final String RETRY_BACKOFF_MS_DOC = "The amount of time to wait before attempting to retry a failed request to a given topic partition. This avoids repeatedly sending requests in a tight loop under some failure scenarios.";

Comment: RETRIES_CONFIG is unfortunately not available but the second option is.

Comment: I figured I could use `StreamsConfig.producerPrefix(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG)` instead.

Comment: ?? https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/StreamsConfig.java#L408

Comment: Yes, this is not in the list. I might be using an older StreamConfig.class but I cannot change it. The properties I added don't seem to work by the way. I am getting a TimeOutException (caused by me) after 60 seconds and the program shuts down.

Comment: My StreamsConfig is this https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/1.0/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/StreamsConfig.java

Comment: After playing with the values I think it works although I don't understand what is the order of the events. Send message -> timeout error -> retry -> backoff -> retry -> backoff etc?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a retry-able for that portion of code, you can manually write it like:

```
Something smt = kStreamBuilder.stream("streamingTopic1");
            .mapValues(String::toUpperCase)
            .groupByKey()
            .reduce((String value1, String value2) -> value1 + value2,
                    TimeWindows.of(1000),
                    "windowStore")
            .toStream()
            .map((windowedId, value) -> new KeyValue<>(windowedId.key(), value))
            .filter((i, s) -> s.length() > 40)
            .collectToSomething();

while (true) {
    try {
        return smt.to("streamingTopic2");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            // log
        }
    }
}
```

Ultimately, you don't want to do the `while` forever, so you can optionally create a retry limit

Comment: That is an interesting solution. I will apply it and let you know.

Comment: I don't recommend this, this will cause a rebalance in the case where a failure occurs for a time period greater than the polling time (by default 5 mins I believe)